# Compute a moving average by group in SQL

Tags: sql

Using SQL I can compute a moving average like this

```
SELECT id,date,var,AVG(var) OVER (ORDER BY  UNIX_DATE(DATE(date)) RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS var_mov_avg_7d
FROM table_name
WHERE id LIKE '2001'
```

But how can I do this separately for all the ids in my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `partition by`:

```
SELECT id,date,var,
       AVG(var) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                      ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(DATE(date))
                      RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                     ) AS var_mov_avg_7d
FROM table_name;
```